# WordPress wp_remote_post() return empty array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm sending the simple request with `wp_remote_post` and everytime it returns an empty array.

My Code

```
$url           = 'https://example.com/page.php';
$email         = get_option( 'admin_email' );
$fields = array(
    'email'             => $email,
    'site'              => get_site_url(),
    );
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'timeout'     => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking'    => false,
    'headers'     => array(),
    'body'        => $fields,
    )
);


if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
    echo 'Response:<pre>';
    print_r( $response );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

and the response I get is:

```
Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
        )

    [body] => 
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 
            [message] => 
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [http_response] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've set the parameter `blocking` to `false`.

It makes the call asynchronous and thus your code won't wait for the response, but just continues executing (which is the purpose of the non blocking parameter).

Set `blocking` to `true` and you will receive the response.